# Use apply/map for pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas dataframe:

```
df.text[:3]

0    nena shot by me   httptcodcrsfqyvh httpstcokxr...
1           full version of soulless    httptcowfmcyyu
2    when youre having a good day but then get to w...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Basically it just a series with tweets text. Nothing more.

```
text = df.text
text.index

Int64Index([0, 1, 2, ...], dtype='int64')
```

Now I want to split words in this series. It works just fine with this one:

```
df.text.str.split('')

0     [nena shot by me   httptcodcrsfqyvh httpstcokx...
1          [full version of soulless    httptcowfmcyyu]
2     [when youre having a good day but then get to ...
```

But id does not work with `apply` method:

```
df.text.apply(lambda x: x.split(' '))
```

and throws an exception: `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'`

What am I doing wrong and why apply method takes this int index as parameter?

Same thing if I use `df.text.map(lambda x: x.split(' '))`

UPD

```
df[df.text == np.nan].shape
(0, 13)
```

And

```
df.text[:3]

0    nena shot by me   httptcodcrsfqyvh httpstcokxr...
1           full version of soulless    httptcowfmcyyu
2    when youre having a good day but then get to w...
```

Works just fine:

```
df.text[:3].map(lambda x: x.split())

0    [nena, shot, by, me, httptcodcrsfqyvh, httpstc...
1        [full, version, of, soulless, httptcowfmcyyu]
2    [when, youre, having, a, good, day, but, then,...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Is one of the values in the text column `NaN`?

Comment: You probably have missing values try `df.text.dropna().apply(lambda x: x.split(' '))`

Comment: @ajcr thanks) I guess it was an issue, I will update my answer with this

Comment: any ideas why df.text.str.split('') works?

Comment: b/c i converts to the column to a string instead of the mixed types (`np.nan` is a float value)